# What is the difference between Spatial autocorrelation and autocorrelation

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, spatial, definition

Am working on classification of some diseases and i have successfully applies the spatial autocorrelation. But i reall want know the distinct difference between Spatial autocorrelation and autocorrelation.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, autocorrelation is used to measure correlation between variables which measure "the same thing", but at different points in time.

Spatial autocorrelation is the same, only that it measures correlation between variables measuring "the same thing", but observed at different spatial locations, such as geographical coordinates.  Since space is multidimensional (usually 2 or 3) while time is onedimensional, spatial autocorrelation in practice have a rather different flavour from autocorrelation in time.